# Visual Studio 2010 Stylesheet partially applied on iis7 - fine on local host

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010, iis-7

I have a VS 2010 C# project that has only one stylesheet.  When I run on local host, the stylesheet applies correctly, however when I run the site from IIS7, using the same IE8 browser, the styles are only partially applied.  I am leaning towards a web server setting, since browsing the localhost version is ok but the server is not.  However, when I use Chrome to browser the server version, everything is fine.

I've tried several suggestions from various website's, but none seem to work for my situation.

Here is a breakdown:

1. Localhost - VS 2010.  When I right click on the project and select
   "View in Browser", IE 8 loads (version 8.0.7601.17514) and the style
   sheet applies fully.
2. Publish code to iis7.  Lunch Internet Explorer (same version as localhost) and navigate to the site - Styles partially apply.
3. Publish code to iis7.  Launch Chrome and navigate to the site - Styles apply correctly.

If the incorrectly applied styles didn't work on localhost, I would assume that the styles don't work in IE8, but because they do, I'm very confused.

Because of the locked down environment I'm working in, IE8 is my only option.

When applied correctly, the menu is aligned to the left and has a border-right of white to separate it from the next menu item.  It also flows horizontally.

When not applied correctly, the menu flows vertically, aligns to the right and is missing the border-right style.

The css that is not being applied is part of the menu:

```
.MainMenu
{
    border-color: #800000;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 0;
    float: right;
    font: bold 13px Arial;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #800000;
}

    .MainMenu a
{
    float: right;
}

    .MainMenu li
{
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 1px;
}

    .MainMenu li a
{
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    color: white;
    float: right;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

    .MainMenu li a:visited
{
    color: white;
}


    .MainMenu li a:hover, .MainMenu li a.current
{
    color: white;
}
```

The menu is on the master page:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>   
    <link href="~/Styles/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <div class="divTopPage"> 
            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Group Name &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Loggedin User:&nbsp;&nbsp; "></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="lblUserName" runat="server" Text="Name Goes here" ></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <br />
         <div class="pageHeader" >
            <asp:Image ID="imgLogo" CssClass="image" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/logo.gif" />
            <asp:Label ID="Label1"  runat="server" Text="App Name" CssClass="labelPageTitle"></asp:Label>
        </div>        

        <div>
            <hr style="padding: 0px; border: .5px solid #000000; background-color: #000000" />
            <hr style="padding: 0px; border: 1px solid #000000; background-color: #000000"  />
            <hr style="padding: 0px; border: .5px solid #000000; background-color: #000000"  />

         <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" CssClass="MainMenu" 
               DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" Font-Names="Verdana" ForeColor="white" StaticSubMenuIndent="5px" >
            <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="black" ForeColor="White" />
            <DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
            <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="black" />
            <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="black" />
           <Items>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Home"  NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Utilities" Value="Utility">
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Centralized Solutions" Value="Centralized Solutions" NavigateUrl="http://CentralizedSolutions"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Daive" Value="Daive" NavigateUrl="http://Daive"></asp:MenuItem>

                <asp:MenuItem Text="Reports" Value="Reports">
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Reports" Value="Reports" NavigateUrl="http://sql-wimssrs/Reports"></asp:MenuItem>
                </asp:MenuItem> 
            </Items>
            <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="black" ForeColor="White" />
            <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
            <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" />
        </asp:Menu>
        </div>
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">        
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Is my problem as simple as IE8 not rendering correctly (but if so, why does it work when using localhost)?

What I've tried so far:

1. Upgraded the .Net framework on the webserver from 2.0 to 4
2. Added a handler specific for css on the web site
3. Tried to confirm the Static setting, but can't because I am not a local admin on the web server.

I greatly appreciate any help, since i have spent several hours over the last few days trying to figure this out.